# name of main thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Can we able to change the name of main thread?
and in main method

```
Thread t = Thread.currentThread();  
System.out.println(t);
```

It prints  :

```
Thread[main,5,main]
```

- here first thread name , second priority, third is thread group to which current thread belongs to.

Is it right?

What is thread group the third parameter?

Comment: Err so what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the Javadoc for [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

> public final void setName(String name)
>
> Changes the name of this thread to be equal to the argument name.

and

> public String toString()
>
> Returns a string representation of this thread, including the thread's name, priority, and thread group.

---

```
Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
System.out.println(t);
t.setName("new thread name");
System.out.println(t);
```

prints

```
Thread[main,5,main]
Thread[new thread name,5,main]
```

To change the ThreadGroup's name you could use reflection but that's unlikely to be a good idea.

Comment: Isn't setName going to throw an exception when trying to change the name of an already running thread?

Comment: The only exception is it will throw a `SecurityException` if your `SecurityManager` doesn't allow changing the name which suggests it is expected that the SecurityManager can allow you to change it.

Comment: @Fildor.. No it will not throw exception.. You can change name of a running thread..  (Yeah that internal part about `Security Manager` I didn't knew.. Thanks Peter..

Comment: If you `start()` a thread more than once you get an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: Right. I just had something in mind, which you cannot change anymore after the thread has been started. And I thought it was the name (which it is not). I'll remember what it was, when I'm not thinking about it anymore ...

Answer (score -2):

The correct way of getting the name of the current thread is

```
System.out.println("Name of Thread is " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

where currentThread() is a static method of the Thread class, which refers to current thread in execution; and getName() is the function which gives the name of that thread.

Comment: Thread#toString() calls the same thing: https://github.com/dmlloyd/openjdk/blob/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#L1449-L1464

The question is how to change the name, and what the thread concept is about - this answer does not seem to add details on that.